# Libgdx Installation gdx-setup.jar file missing

Tags: java, installation, libgdx, frameworks, game-development

So I have watched several videos  and read through many a forum post on installing libgdx with android development studio.  Every time someone opens the gdx-setup.jar download there is a file within names gdx-setup.jar that you click on and brings up a setup project menu.  However each time i download this file is missing and this is all I find within the download.

Here is a link to the picture of what I get when I open the libgdx download, (since I do not have the 10 reputation yet to include the picture in my post.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jei9d.png

Just trying to get this framework setup so I can start learning more about using it in game development.

Comment: Can you describe what you have on the picture? Overtime the link might become broken

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Creating%20Projects.html#quick-start) explains how to run the downloaded `setup-gdx.jar` to create a new project.

I guess, you're missing the part (or your OS is not picking up the correct application to run the `jar` file with [should be java]) how to run the downloaded jar:

> Open up your command line tool, go to the download folder and run:

```
java -jar gdx-setup.jar
```

After that, if your OS has `java` or `jre` or `jdk` installed and configured correctly (`JAVA_HOME` variable set and exported) you should be able to see the UI.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it figured out.  I was having problems because I downloaded Android studio and the embedded jre was causing issues so I just downloaded a jdk so I could set the path variable and now I got it to run!

Comment: Glad it helped.